# Hazelcast Jet not allowing Tomcat to stop

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am using  Hazelcast jet to some aggregation and grouping but after being idle for sometime and when I tried to stop my tomcat it is not allowing to stop my tomcat and I have restart my PC. Below is the error which I am getting. Please anyone can guide me what it exactly error is showing and how to shutdown it gracefully?

```
Sending multicast datagram failed. Exception message saying the operation is not permitted 

usually means the underlying OS is not able to send packets at a given pace. It can be caused by starting several hazelcast members in parallel when the members send their join message nearly at the same time.
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: Datagram send failed
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:291)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:113)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:77)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
```

Code is quite huge but I tried show you some sample may it won't work as it is just glimpse of a code:

```
 Class Abc{
        // It Create Jet Instance
        JetConfig jetConfig = new JetConfig();
        jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().setProperty( "hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j" );
        jetConfig.getInstanceConfig().setCooperativeThreadCount(5);
        jetConfig.configureHazelcast(c -> {
            c.getNetworkConfig().setReuseAddress(true);
            c.setClusterName("DATA" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            c.getNetworkConfig().setPort(9093);
            c.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress("localhost");
            c.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);  
        });
        JetInstance jetInstance= Jet.newJetInstance(jetConfig);

  
    public Pipeline createPipeline() {
        return Pipeline.create();
    }
    
    // To Add Job to pipeline
    public void joinPipeToJet(Pipeline pl, String name) {
        JobConfig j = new JobConfig();
        //j.setProcessingGuarantee(ProcessingGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        j.setName(name);
        jetInstance.newJob(pl,j).join();
    }


    public void readJsonFile(final Map<String, Object> data) {
         // Random Id for job so I can separate two jobs Imaps
        String jobid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        try {
            Pipeline pl = createPipeline();
            UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
            
            
             final IMap<Object, Object> abc = jetInstance.getMap(idOne.toString());
             abc.putAll(data);
            
             // Reading data from file and sending data to next
             final BatchSource batchSource = Sources.map(abc);
             
                   pl.readFrom(batchSource)
                        .writeTo(Sinks.map(this.uid));
                    
            joinPipeToJet(pl, jobid);
             abc.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Job j1 = jetInstance.getJob(jobid);
            if (j1 != null) {
                j1.cancel();
            }
        } finally {
            Job j1 = jetInstance.getJob(jobid);
            if (j1 != null) {
                j1.cancel();
            }
        }
    }

//Process to mainplate data and returning it using BatchStage to Map
public Map<String, Object> runProcess(final Pipeline pl) {
    String jobid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    UID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    BatchStage<Object> bd1 = ;//get data by calling method 
                                  
     bd1.writeTo(Sinks.list(idOne.toString()));
    joinPipeToJet(pl, jobid);
    IList<Object> abc = jetInstance.getList(idOne.toString());
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList(abc);
                                     
                                     
    final Map<String, Object> finalresult =new HashMap<String, Object>();
    finalresult.put("datas", result.get(0));
    abc.destroy();
    return finalresult;

}

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            p.putAll("Some Data");
            readJsonFile(p);
            Pipeline pl = createPipeline();
            runProcess(pl);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also share your code how you start and stop Jet?

Comment: @FrantišekHartman , Thanks for the response Yes I have added sample code yes may it is not well formatted as I have take pieces of code from main code, hope it help you to understand.

Comment: I don't see in your code the shutdown of the Jet instance (i.e. `jetInstance.shutdown()`). You have to do it explicitly as Hazelcast creates a set of non-daemon threads. IMO the MulticastService exception is not related to your problem. You can switch to tcp-ip discovery (NetworkConfig/JoinConfig/TcpIpConfig) and this issue should disappear.

Comment: @kwart, Hi yes I am doing shutdown at time of tomcat shutdown on contextDestroy, I am not shutting it down on every job completion as Hazelcast takes time to start again, can you please let me know difference between MultiCast and Tcp-ip and what will be best configuration for it, sorry as I am little new to Hazelcast so some concepts are still not clear to me.

Comment: Multicast and TcpIp are the basic discovery methods to find other cluster members (i.e. Jet instances). The Multicast one joins a multicast group (socket address) and finds about other members by sending/receiving datagrams to/from the group. In the TcpIp one you preconfigures manually member addresses (e.g. `networkConfig.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember("192.168.1.1:5701").addMember("192.168.1.2:5701")`).
BTW. Do you use more cluster members or do you work on a single Jet instance only? (in such case you wouldn't need a discovery method enabled at all).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation , Right now we have just one Jet instance but multiple Jobs will be added to it time to time.

Comment: Hmm, as I have just one Jet Instance so not added TcpIp configuration but I don't it will help as it  seems to be something else not sure may be I am wrong, not able to find exact reason.